# MS Access SQL Query Help to change from Read Only

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query, which checks the Status in the OrderDetail table, and checks that all the items in the StatusFK = 2, only when all the corrosponding items have the status 2 then i want to run an update query to update the Status of the Order table to 2.

The problem i am having with the bellow code is its only read only so i cannot link it to an update query.

Any help would be great!

```
 SELECT tblOrder.OrderPK
 FROM tblOrder INNER JOIN tblOrderDetail ON tblOrder.OrderPK = tblOrderDetail.OrderFK
 GROUP BY tblOrder.OrderPK
 HAVING Count(tblOrderDetail.OrderFK )   = SUM(IiF (tblOrderDetail.StatusFK = 2 ,1,0) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT tblOrder.OrderPK
FROM tblOrder
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tblOrderDetail
    WHERE tblOrderDetail.OrderFK = tblOrder.OrderPK
    AND tblOrderDetail.StatusFK <> 2
)
```

This query will select all rows from `tblOrder` which don't have any non-status-2 child rows.

Comment: Opps my Bad! I will post a new question, Just one thing with the SQL you helped me with. I want to NOT show records in the tblOrder which already have a StatusFK of 2? Do i just add an AND Not on the end of the script?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and probably a good thing to do rather than re-updating those rows.

Comment: Im sure its very simple but i have tried AND tblOrder.StatusFK <> 2 and the end?, but im not getting the result i need??

Comment: Got there in the end thank you! UPDATE tblOrder SET tblOrder.Statusfk = 2
WHERE tblOrder.Statusfk<>2 AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
                  FROM tblOrderDetail
                  WHERE tblOrderDetail.OrderFK = tblOrder.OrderPK AND
                        tblOrderDetail.StatusFK <> 2  );

Answer (score 0):

Completed SQL with the Extra WHERE clause! all working a treat!

```
UPDATE tblOrder SET tblOrder.Statusfk = 2
WHERE tblOrder.Statusfk<>2 AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
              FROM tblOrderDetail
              WHERE tblOrderDetail.OrderFK = tblOrder.OrderPK AND
                    tblOrderDetail.StatusFK <> 2  );
```